# Geany Symbol List - Function scope

Tags: c++, geany

I use Geany to edit .C C++ source files. The sidebar shows me a list of functions in my current file. Some of these functions are written fully with scopes, others are listed just by the name of the function, eg

```
Foam::hexRef4::addFace[1441]
distribute[5829]
```

etc. These two functions are both private member functions of the hexRef4 class, within the Foam namespace. They are both declared in a header file, hexRef4.H, which is included at the top of the source file.

If I change the function list from "by name" to "by appearance", then the issue remains, although which functions have the full scope listed change.

Some googling highlighted a similar known bug if the function returns a pointer to class object, in which case the function is listed as belonging to the class type it returns a pointer to, but none of the functions I am using return pointers.

This happens both with and without scope for functions with and without return types, before and after constructors in the source file.

If I move the constructors to the top of the source file, then the function list is fully alphabetised but has a group of functions alphabetised by h, for Foam::hexRef4::functionNameHere.

Any suggestions/solutions appreciated

Comment: You should check whether you are using latest Geany (1.23.1) and wether it might still occur in current git and report a bug to geany in case of. This is nothing for stackoverflow IMHO.